# Get unique value from data base according to date, when user click on date then expand the details as available in database

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

Get unique value from data base according to date, when user click on date then expand the details as available in database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZizL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When the page load call the following query to list the `distinct date`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT date FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

When the user click on `+`, invoke the following query with the selected date

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date = '12-AUG-2020';
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank for the help.....while using this (SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date = '12-AUG-2020';) code in php im getting only 1 records whereas for the particular date there are total 30 rows which i want to get. ------------------------------------------<?php 

require_once 'php_action/db_connect.php';

if($_GET['date']) {
 $date = $_GET['date'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE NAME WHERE date = '$date'";
 $result = pg_query($connection, $sql);
 $data = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

 pg_close($connection);

?>

Comment: Can you add the sample data in the question? if the date format is not proper then, it will create trouble. Try the `Query` in `pgAdmin`. If it returns 30 rows, then it's `php` code problem else `date format`.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your support to complete my project. there was issue of php code. i have completed project with two solution as given above by you.

Comment: Don't use `SIR`. Use `NAME` of the person in `stackoverflow`. If possible use `NAME` everywhere. Don't use `SIR`.